# How use findutils in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have installed findutils in Suse11 with yast2:

```
yast2 -i findutils
```

Seem all gone ok, but when I run e.g. locate - command not found. How I can install findutils so that can be accessible only by names?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `findutils-locate` package.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of findutils may not contain locate. Try:

yast2 -i findutils-locate